# Вопрос по api камеры

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Мне нужно сделать сканирование qr кода в приложении, для этого я использую библиотеку `zxing core`, и `android.hardware.Camera` но с api 23+ `android.hardware.Camera` больше не поддерживается, и как то сложно использовать для api 14+ одно api для более новых версий новое api.

Может есть какое-нибудь решение что бы использовать старое api на новых устройствах (даже если это увеличит размер приложение, не сильно важно), может есть библиотеки что бы абстрагироваться от этих различий, или еще какие-нибудь варианты при наименьших усилиях?

Answer (score 1):

Писать разный код под разные версии системы - нормальная практика. Система постоянно обновляется и неизбежно появляются новые `API`. При этом устаревшие редко полностью удаляют и, обычно, они работают и на новых версиях. При этом компилятор лишь выделяет устаревшие методы как `Deprecated` (есть вероятность, что через `n` лет поддержку устаревшего класса совсем отменят). Вот новые `API` обычно не сразу работают для старых версий и не всегда включаются впоследствии в библиотеки поддержки.